# Store RAM and PROGMEM strings in one variable

Tags: c++, progmem

I want to store a number of strings in an object. Currently I have:

```
class MyClass {
  int numStrings = 0;
  ??? strings[20];

  public:
    void addString(const char str[]);
    void print();
};

void MyClass::addString(const char str[]) {
  strings[numStrings] = str;
  numStrings++;
}

void MyClass::print() {
  for (int i = 0 ; i < numStrings ; i++) {
    Serial.println(strings[i]);
  }
}
```

`Serial.println()` works with strings in RAM and in PROGMEM alike.

Is there a type that I can give to my `strings` variable that allows me to store both types of strings?

```
MyClass s;

s.addString("This should work");
s.addString(F("This should work, too"));
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a type that I can give to my strings variable that allows me to store both types of strings?

No, but you could tag the pointer or add a vector with type information or ultimately use a class hierarchy (BaseString<-SRAMString, PROMEMString).

As a pointer is 16-bit (Arduino Uno) and there is limited amount of SRAM it is possible to add a magic number to pointers to determine the address space.

Obviously the print() member function will have to use the right type and you will also need a new addString for F() strings. Check how F() is defined.

Cheers!

Comment: I don't know how to "tag a pointer", but when working with a magic number I would make that a void pointer?

Comment: Here is an example of mapping EEPROM, SRAM and PROGMEM to a single address space: https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Arduino-Shell/blob/master/Shell.h#L1058

Comment: The simplest scheme is to use the sign bit for PROGMEM, i.e. add 0x8000 to PROGMEM pointers.

Comment: I don't get it. So when I get a `__FlashStringHelper*` I add 0x8000 to mark that it points to PROGMEM. But then I still can't store that in a `const char*` variable, can I?

Comment: Tell the compiler what you want: `uint16_t str = 0x8000U + (uint16_t) str_P; strings[numStrings++] = (const char*) str;`

Comment: That is the answer I was looking for. :) Is there a type...? -> Yes, `uint16_t`.

Comment: Actually the standard type (stdint.h) is `uintptr_t`. Here are the details: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer. Please remember that the standard was not intended for a Harvard architecture as the AVR.